# Highcharts display scrollbar when zooming

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

Zooming with a zoomType of 'x' in a Highcharts chart, seems to only crop the data area between given coordinate stops. Is there a way to zoom in and still have all data available through scrolling?

```
{
  chart: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    zoomType: "x",
    scrollablePlotArea: {
      scrollPositionX: 1,
      minWidth: 1057
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/OysteinAmundsen/4x7yzu68/3/

The fiddle above is set to a minimum width of 1057px, while the max-width of the container is 800px. This forces a horizontal scrollbar. If you zoom in on the data, notice that the available scrolling area does not change. This means that the data is not zoomed, it is cropped and stretched to fill the area.

I know there are events I can hook on to - the redraw event seems a likely candidate. Perhaps I can adjust the minWidth and cancel the crop-zoom, or is there a config I'm missing wihch whould do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `scrollbar` feature from Highstock:

```
scrollbar: {
    enabled: true
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/be5wvg9q/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/scrollbar